# breezejs inlineCount is not working (CORS cross domain http request)

Tags: jquery, odata, breeze

here's my query:

```
 var query = breeze.EntityQuery
                .from("Mandates").skip(offset).take(pageSize).inlineCount(true);

        return manager.executeQuery(query);
```

In the response headers, I can see the count is returned by the server:

```
X-InlineCount:63
```

However, in the succeed handler when I do:

```
 var results = data.results;
 var recordCount = data.inlineCount;
```

results contains the correct records. However data.inlineCount is null.

How come ?

**EDIT**

getAllResponseHeaders does not return all headers ! I've just noticed most of them are missing, including X-InlineCount.

I believe this is because I'm doing a cross-domain http request (website is in localhost but my webapi (web service) is on a server on the domain). How can this be fixed ?

Comment: at one point, breeze makes a call to the jquery getResponseHeader function and passes X-InlineCount as the key property. However responseHeadersString  is very incomplete and does not contain this property, hence the bug in my application. The problem is that in the response headers in Chrome I can see that the property is definitely here, along with many others that are NOT in responseHeadersString. Is it a bug in jquery ?  I got the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. You have to configure your server to expose the X-InlineCount header. If you are using a project ASP .NET Web API you have to put the next lines in your web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="X-InlineCount" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Also, I had problem with firefox, but in the last version of firefox, the problem is solved.

(Yo don't need to use all the lines, it's only an example) ;)

-----EDIT-----

I had forgotten, because it was log time ago. The browser ,when you are doing a CORS call, sends first a Option call to check if it is possible to do a CORS call and what things are allowed. So you have to implement a message handler in your WEB API project for manage this OPTION call. The implementation is the next:

```
public class OptionsHttpMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Options)
            {
                var apiExplorer = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer();


                var controllerRequested = request.GetRouteData().Values["controller"] as string;
                var supportedMethods =  apiExplorer.ApiDescriptions
                    .Where(d =>
                    {

                        var controller = d.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
                        return string.Equals(
                            controller, controllerRequested, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                    })
                    .Select(d => d.HttpMethod.Method)
                    .Distinct();

                if (!supportedMethods.Any())
                    return Task.Factory.StartNew(
                        () => request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));

                return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                    resp.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                    resp.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Security,Token-Access");
                    resp.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,OPTIONS");
                    resp.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-InlineCount");

                    return resp;
                });
            }

            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

You can omit the next section if you put that in your web.config.

```
resp.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
resp.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Security,Token-Access");
resp.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,OPTIONS");
resp.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-InlineCount");
```

I hope that this help to solve your problem.

PD: Sorry for my english, it is not my first language.

Comment: thanks so much, I'll try that tomorrow morning and I'll let you know if it worked.

Comment: This solution worked for me, the only two things that I think that can cause the problem is: 1. Have you put the lines in the web.config in the right position? 2. What browser are you using? you need to use the last version. This solution worked for me in the last version of chrome. In the next link you can find more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: In this other link there is also goog information: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/?redirect_from_locale=es

Comment: that worked by the way. However for some reason I could not get it to work between two instances of Visual Studio with the service running on localhost on a specific port in IIS express, and the web application also running on localhost on a different port.

Answer (score 3):

**We have confirmed the problem. We plan to fix it by moving the `inlineCount` out of the headers and into the results payload** where it probably should have been in the first place. No firm date for that but soon.

> UPDATE: 4/18/2013. We have implemented this fix internally and it passes our tests. We'll deploy in the next NuGet (the one after 1.3.0). I'll update this answer again when that happens.

We reproduced the problem, as anyone can do, by tweaking [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wardbell/r2kcB/).

The fiddle makes requests to a Breeze server that exposes Todos. Naturally, the Breeze server is in a different domain than jsFiddle and therefore requires CORS to perform query and save operations.

I changed the `getAllTodos` method to the following:

```
function getAllTodos() {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Todos")

    // added for Cross-Origin inlineCount header testing
    .orderBy('Description')
    .skip(1).take(3)
    .inlineCount(true);

    log("Getting Todos");
    return manager.executeQuery(query)
    .then(querySucceeded).fail(failed);

    function querySucceeded(data) {
        var count = data.results.length;
        log("Retrieved " + count);

        // added for Cross-Origin inlineCount header testing
        log("Inline count: "+ data.inlineCount);
        log("Headers: " + data.XHR.getAllResponseHeaders());

        if (!count) {
            log("No Todos"); return;
        }
        viewModel.items(data.results);
    }
}
```

**@jvrdelafuente** - I'm surprised that the Web.config change you recommended actually worked. I'd have thought that such a change to the Web.config would only affect what the server does, not what the browser does.

When I examine network traffic, I can see that the server is sending the "X-InlineCount" header, *with or without your suggested change*. The browser (IE10 and Chrome at least) appears to be hiding the header from jQuery.AJAX, which is responsible for AJAX communications in the typical breeze app.

I see this effect when I add the following to a query success callback:

```
 console.log("Headers: " + data.XHR.getAllResponseHeaders());
```

The log shows very few of the headers actually returned by the server.

Perhaps when you add

```
<add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="X-InlineCount" />
```

to the Web.config, the server can tell the browser that it is OK to expose the "X-InlineCount" header to the JavaScript client.

I confess I didn't investigate that possibility; perhaps it is a viable work-around in the short run.

But it's only a band-aide as far as we're concerned. We don't want developers to have to worry about this kind of thing; CORS creates enough headaches as it is. So we're going to communicate the `inlineCount` in the payload rather than the headers ... and remove this concern all together.

Comment: Ok, good to know. It did not make sense to me either why the inline-count was in the headers. It actually took me a while to realize that as I was looking for it in the resultset.